# Transform a table with multiple rows to a table with ONE LINE PER OPERATION NUMBER (OPE_NUM) using Common Table expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server, and i want to be able to transform a table with multiple rows to a table with ONE LINE PER OPERATION NUMBER (OPE_NUM) and multiple new columns using Common table expressions

here is my SQL query to get a set of OPERATIONS (WITH DUPLICATE OPE_NUM) :

```
SELECT * from OPERATION OPE
              LEFT OUTER JOIN CAPITALISATION CAP ON
                   OPE.num_op = CAP.num_op
                   OPE.date = CAP.date
              LEFT OUTER JOIN SECURITIES  ON
                   OPE.CODE = S.CODE
                   OPE.date = S.DATE
              LEFT JOIN CAPIS CS ON
                   OPE.num_op = CS.operation
                   OPE.date = CS.date
    where OPE.date = '20200930'
```

This query is giving me a result set (with multiple rows) like the following :

```
 ACCOUNT   CURR   AMOUNT1   AMOUNTRES   AMOUNTREG   DEVCODE   OPE_NUM
 111111    USD    -200000   0           0           xxxx-E    123456
 222222    USD    200000    1           2           xxxx-I    123456
 555555    USD    400000    0           0           xxxx-C    123456
 333333    USD    -7        0           0           xxxx-I    56789
 444444    USD    0         0           -34000      xxxx-C    3456789
 666666    USD    2         50000       0           yyyy-C    12454678
 777777    EUR    600000    500         0           ZZZZ-X    12454678
```

What i am expecting is to transform this list (using Common Table expressions) to a table with one row per OPE_NUM and new other columns like below :

```
GPACCOUNT   EACCOUNT   VACCOUNT   EAMOUNT   OPE_NUM
555555      111111     222222     400000    123456
null        null       333333       -7      56789
444444      NULL       NULL          0      3456789
NULL        NULL       NULL       600002    12454678
```

- GPACCOUNT is populated when the initial query result conditions are satisfied :
  AMOUNT1 > 0 AND AMOUNTRES = AMOUNTREG = 0 AND DEVCODE = xxxx-C (for each OPE_NUM)
- EACCOUNT is populated when the initial query result conditions are
  satisfied :
  AMOUNT 1 < 0 and AMOUNTRES = AMOUNTREG = 0 AND DEVCODE = xxxx-E(for each OPE_NUM)
- VACCOUNT is populated when the initial query result conditions are
  satisfied :
  AMOUNT1 > 0 AND AMOUNTRES = AMOUNTREG = 0 AND DEVCODE = xxxx-I(for each OPE_NUM)
- EAMOUNT  is populated when when the initial query result conditions
  are satisfied :
  SUM(AMOUNT1) (for each OPE_NUM : 123456) ==> 200000-200000+ 200000

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: What about if there is multiple gpaccount or eaccount for single OPE_NUM

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur Yes, for every single OPE_NUM there will always be one GPACCOUNT and one EACCOUNT.

Example for OPE_NUM = 123456 we have 1 GPACCOUNT and 1 EACCOUNT

Answer (score 0):

You can use cte and group by to achieve your desired result as you need but some of your condition is not right I think. For example there is no vaccount which satisfy your condition. Please check:

```
with cte as (
select ACCOUNT, CURR    ,AMOUNT1    ,AMOUNTRES, AMOUNTREG,  DEVCODE,    OPE_NUM, 
(case when amount1>0 and amountres= 0 and amountreg=0 AND DEVCODE = 'xxxx-C' then account end) as GPAccount ,
(case when amount1<0 and amountres= 0 and amountreg=0 AND DEVCODE = 'xxxx-E' then account end) as EACCOUNT ,
(case when amount1>0 and amountres= 0 and amountreg=0 AND DEVCODE = 'xxxx-I' then account end) as VACCOUNT ,
(sum(amount1) over(partition by ope_num) ) as EAMOUNT
from (SELECT * from OPERATION OPE
              LEFT OUTER JOIN CAPITALISATION CAP ON
                   OPE.num_op = CAP.num_op
                   OPE.date = CAP.date
              LEFT OUTER JOIN SECURITIES  ON
                   OPE.CODE = S.CODE
                   OPE.date = S.DATE
              LEFT JOIN CAPIS CS ON
                   OPE.num_op = CS.operation
                   OPE.date = CS.date
    where OPE.date = '20200930')t
) select max(GPAccount),max(EAccount),max(VAccount),max(EAmount),OPE_NUM from cte group by ope_num
```

**Output:**

[image]